# Make specific tag visible only to logged in users in front-end

Tags: conditional-tags

I have this specific tag I need to assign to my posts but I need to hide it from regular visitors so that only logged in people can see it. How do I go about it? What WordPress function/hook should I be looking into?

I know that I could use `is_user_logged_in()` and I am also looking into [`is_tag()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag), but how do I put this together? Currently I'm having it displayed in my single template with [`the_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags), but it doesn't seem to offer a parameter to exclude a particular tag.

Pseudo code would be: if user is logged in then show all tags except a specific tag.

Comment: So, solution if fine but how do I make the solution to work for two or more tags ? Anyone or should I be asking this in a new question. ?

Comment: got it. `if($tag->slug=='tag_one' OR $tag->slug=='tag_two'){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `add_filter` to your theme's `functions.php` file

```
function myTags() {
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
      if($tag->slug=='your specific tag slug'){
        if(is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<a href='.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).' >'.$tag->name . '</a> '; 
        }
    } else {
         echo '<a href='.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'>'.$tag->name . '</a> '; 
    }
  }
}
}
add_filter('the_tags', 'myTags');
```

Comment: Works perfectly. What changes will be made if there are two or more tags to be exluded ?

Comment: @gurung add more tags in `if condition` with `OR` operator

Comment: @DipaliDhole `if($tag->slug=='tag_one' OR 'tag_two') {` does not work. also how come the code works with the same if statement, amazing.

Comment: It is the same but the first `<a>` is echoed only for logged users, so it won't be visible for not logged users (but not logged users can still access to the tag archive URL if they know it).